# How to filter array with other array

Tags: react-native

I have two array, One of them is like this:

```
 const array1 =  [
      Object {
        "ItemId": 1,
        
      },
      Object {
        "ItemId": 2,
        
      },
    ]
```

other array is :

```
     const array2 = [
      Object {
        "obj1": Object {
    
          "Id": 4736,
    
        },
        "obj2": Object {
    
          "ItemId": 1,
     
        },
      }
]
```

*I want to get items in array1, which are not equals in obj2 of array2 .*

*I tried this but doesnt work*

```
array1.filter(function (item) {
        return array2.map((x) => {
          return x.obj2 != item;
        });
```

Comment: array2 Isn't a valid array? Did something go wrong when copy/pasting?

Comment: There are three issues that immediately catch my eye:

1. array1.filter is expecting a truthy value and array2.map is always returning an array. In this case it will always be truthy.

2. array2.map is just creating a new array with the results of the callback function (x.obj2 != item). This will return an array filled with boolean values. [true, false, true]

3. The comparison looks off to me. Are both objects (item and x.obj) referring to the same object reference? If not, you might rather compare item.ItemId with obj2.ItemId.

Comment: @webwelten u are right it return boolean. It is my mistake. Actually I want to get object. and also they referring same object. i can filter with ItemId as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of array2.map, you're looking for [Array.protype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Why?

array1.filter is expecting a truthy value for every item.

array2.map is returning an array (!) with the results of its callback. In your case it's the result of each comparisson `x.obj2 != item`. It could look something like this: `[true, false]`. But this array will always evaluate to true.

array2.some() or array2.every() also iterate over the array but will return a boolean for the condition you're using. You can try for yourself and check the code sample afterwards.

```js
 const array1 =  [
  {
    "ItemId": 1,
  },
  {
    "ItemId": 2,
  },
];
    
const array2 = [
  {
    "obj1": {
      "ItemId": 4736,
    },
    "obj2": {
      "ItemId": 1,
    },
  },
];

// errornous filter usage
const test = array1.filter(item => {
  const arr = array2.map(x => x.obj2 !== item); 
  return arr;
});

// suggestion
const filteredResult = array1.filter(item => {
  // both ways work
  // return array2.every(x => x.obj2.ItemId !== item.ItemId); 
  return !array2.some(x => x.obj2.ItemId === item.ItemId); 
  });

console.log('initial result', test);
console.log('correct result', filteredResult);
```

Comment: I answered your question above

Comment: oh it almost work ! actually it  works however when array2 has no item it returns an error just

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
array1=array1.filter((item) => {
    return array2[0].obj2.ItemId !== item.ItemId;
})
```

Comment: how can i handle if array2 has more object ?